# Treat symbolic-link as separate files while visiting

Tags: buffers, symbolic-links

Is there a way to make Emacs visit already visited file(with active buffer) via symbolic-link as a different file?
I want them(links/file paths) to be visited by different buffers.
It will be best if this behavior can be controlled with a directory local variable.

Why I need it:

I have a bunch of source files under actual project root source directory with a project file (it configures build tools) for production builds.
But I also have those files under a different root (for development environment)
The whole thing resides in the same git repo and has `.dir-locals.el` with:

```
((nil . ((find-file-visit-truename . nil)
         (vc-follow-symlinks       . nil))))
```

It works fine (despite obvious problems with version control).
The only thing that is really inconvenient is that I sometimes visit source files via production root paths and then Emacs always opens them via the paths and it messes up with development tools/Emacs integration. So I have to kill the buffer and re-visit files under develop.

Comment: This is most likely an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe it would be better if you wrote what you actually want to achieve. Two buffers for one file is a sure way to loose edits if the buffers are not generally read-only. Note that you can edit both buffers independently. It may be that you need an `ediff` merge after a while.

Comment: Note that there are methods for having two buffers for the same file: `clone-buffer-indirect`, [`jac`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/47210/2370) available as library [on github](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/jac).

Comment: @Tobias What if the second buffer (if a file already visited via different link) will be opened in a indirect-buffer?

Comment: @Tobias added explanation why I need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [File Aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Aliases.html#File-Aliases):

> Normally, if you visit a file which Emacs is already visiting under a
>       different name, Emacs displays a message in the echo area and uses the
>       existing buffer visiting that file.  This can happen on systems that
>       support hard or symbolic links, or if you use a long file name on a
>       system that truncates long file names, or on a case-insensitive file
>       system.  You can suppress the message by setting the variable
>       `find-file-suppress-same-file-warnings` to a non-‘nil’ value.  You can
>       disable this feature entirely by setting the variable
>       `find-file-existing-other-name` to ‘nil’: then if you visit the same
>       file under two different names, you get a separate buffer for each file
>       name.
>
> If the variable `find-file-visit-truename` is non-nil, then the file name recorded for a buffer is the file's truename (made by replacing all symbolic links with their target names), rather than the name you specify. Setting `find-file-visit-truename` also implies the effect of `find-file-existing-other-name`.

For future reference: this is the first node that comes up in the Emacs Info manual when you type <kbd>i symbolic</kbd>

Comment: I added the `find-file-visit-truename` bit since one can stumble over it.

Comment: I was hoping to convince OP to read the original, either on the web or inside emacs :-)

Comment: I added `find-file-existing-other-name . nil` to my `.dir-locals.el` file and it work. Thx